# docusign REST API Embedded Signing Multiple Signers Example

Tags: api, rest, docusignapi

I have web app that I am adding DocuSign Embedded Signing to that is used both on Desktop as well as Mobile device.  I have been told that the iFrame solution of SOAP API is unreliable (as I have also experienced). I am attempting to implement using REST API.  Here is my status:

1. I have successfully executed the REST API Sample for Embedded Signing from the API Walkthrough.
2. I have successfully adapted the envelop to include two different signers, and then successfully completed the signing process for signer1.
3. How do I get the second signer signing session in a browser window?

Is there a sample (or secret sauce) for how to get the embedded signing session for signer2 to launch?

MANY MANY thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a URL token for the second recipient you follow the same process you used for the first recipient.  You make the same http POST request but simply reference the email, username, and clientUserId of your second recipient.

For instance, when you were generating the URL for your first recipient, you probably had a request body similar to this:

```
{
    "returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    "authenticationMethod": "None",
    "email": "email1@gmail.com",
    "userName": "Name 1",
    "clientUserId": "1001"
}
```

The DocuSign system uses the combination of their email, userName and clientUserId to uniquely identify this embedded recipient (also known as a captive recipient).  So when you add your second recipient to the envelope you should have given them their own clientUserId value that's different from the first recipient.  Then, the system will be able to identify them and generate a URL token for this second recipient.

For example, if you added a second recipient to the envelope with the following information:

```
{
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "name": "Second Recipient",
    "roleName": "Signer1",
    "clientUserId": "1002"
}
```

Then you'll want to make the [same http POST call](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm) you made for the first recipient, but with the following information instead:

```
{
    "returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    "authenticationMethod": "None",
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "userName": "Second Recipient",
    "clientUserId": "1002"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So how do I get the opportunity to make the second request? When I finish the signing process for ClientID 1001 it goes to Docusign.com/devcenter site and I never get the opportunity to make the second POST request you suggest :) Do I have to set it to return to my own site page and then relaunch the POST from there?
again, many thanks :)

Comment: Yes with Embedding you control the flow, so you can set the return url to your portal/website and then make the second POST call from there.  When the redirect happens, there should be a URL parameter indicating if the signing was completed, declined, etc, and if you want you could automatically parse that string and make the POST call immediately.  Or you just redirect them back and have a user click a button or something to launch the second POST call, up to your needs...

Comment: Thanks. I'm finding that after the first signer completes, the "redirect" happens back to my page correctly and there is a URL param with the state, cool... however there is no session info anymore, I'm guessing since the call to my page is coming from outside my process. How do you recommend maintaining that info so I know ViewURL/names/emails for next signer POST? (It would be really helpful if there was a complete sample of how the multi-signer embedded signing worked)

Comment: You need to maintain that data on your side.  You know all your recipient information at the time they are added to the envelope right?  Once you know that data you can save it in your local program or your website data, then retrieve it when it's time to make the second POST call.